# Keep branches syncronization in git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a big issue with branching in git.
In project i have 2 big major branches. It's like 2 separate projects with some fundamental distinctions.
But! I need to sync some minor changes in both branches, like small feature that i need in both projects.
I don't want to copy-paste it everytime. Is there any way in git to add some commits from one branch to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something called cherry-pick, here is a usage

```
git cherry-pick [hash]
```

And here is a documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Basically it will allow you to move single commits into different branches, use that command if you can't just merge both branches together.